# Translations for Description / Long Description

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way to add translated text for the app "description" and "Long description". For example: french and spanish? Or how do we handle localization for these text?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the app listing UI does not offer the option to add localized short/long descriptions yet. However, there is an option to define all the languages your app supports under the "Supported languages" question.
https://api.slack.com/reference/slack-apps/directory-submission-checklist.